# Amazon EMR - cannot run program <path> ./mapper.js": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-emr

I am using Nodejs for an Amazon EMR job. I have tried changing the files to use UNIX line endings but it's still not working. Here is the error :-

```
2016-11-27 09:16:53,794 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed exec [/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1480232881564_0005/container_1480232881564_0005_01_000002/./mapper.js]
2016-11-27 09:16:53,803 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.work.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.output.dir
2016-11-27 09:16:53,804 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: map.input.start is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.start
2016-11-27 09:16:53,804 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: job.local.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.local.dir
2016-11-27 09:16:53,804 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.is.map is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.ismap
2016-11-27 09:16:53,805 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
2016-11-27 09:16:53,805 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id
2016-11-27 09:16:53,805 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.local.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.cluster.local.dir
2016-11-27 09:16:53,806 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: map.input.file is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.file
2016-11-27 09:16:53,806 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.on is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.skiprecords
2016-11-27 09:16:53,806 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: map.input.length is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.length
2016-11-27 09:16:53,806 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.cache.localFiles is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.local.files
2016-11-27 09:16:53,807 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
2016-11-27 09:16:53,807 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.partition
2016-11-27 09:16:53,816 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: configuration exception
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1480232881564_0005/container_1480232881564_0005_01_000002/./mapper.js": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
```

Here is my cluster command:-

```
aws emr create-cluster 
--auto-scaling-role EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole 
--applications Name=Hadoop --bootstrap-actions '[{"Path":"s3://ccvikas/installNode.sh","Name":"Custom action"}]' 
--ec2-attributes '{"InstanceProfile":"EMR_EC2_DefaultRole","SubnetId":"subnet-9db906c6","EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup":"sg-d9ee70a4","EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup":"sg-deee70a3"}' 
--service-role EMR_DefaultRole 
--release-label emr-5.2.0 
--steps '[{"Args":["hadoop-streaming","-files","s3://ccvikas/js/mapper.js","-mapper","mapper.js","-reducer","mapper.js","-input","s3://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2016-40/segments/1474738659496.36/warc/CC-MAIN-20160924173739-00000-ip-10-143-35-109.ec2.internal.warc.gz","-output","s3://ccvikas/out8"],"Type":"CUSTOM_JAR","ActionOnFailure":"CANCEL_AND_WAIT","Jar":"command-runner.jar","Properties":"","Name":"Streaming program"}]' 
--name 'My cluster' --instance-groups '[{"InstanceCount":1,"InstanceGroupType":"MASTER","InstanceType":"m1.xlarge","Name":"Master - 1"},{"InstanceCount":1,"InstanceGroupType":"CORE","InstanceType":"m1.xlarge","Name":"Core - 2"}]' 
--scale-down-behavior TERMINATE_AT_INSTANCE_HOUR 
--region us-east-1
```

Here is my steps command:-

```
hadoop-streaming 
-files s3://ccvikas/js/mapper.js,s3://ccvikas/js/reducer.js 
-mapper mapper.js 
-reducer reducer.js 
-input s3://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2016-40/segments/1474738659496.36/warc/CC-MAIN-20160924173739-00000-ip-10-143-35-109.ec2.internal.warc.gz 
-output s3://ccvikas/out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that my bootstrap action wasn't installing the nodejs properly. So I revised my bootstrap actions as follows to install the latest nodejs.

```
#!/bin/bash
is_aml=`uname -r | grep amzn1.x86_64 | wc -l`

if [ is_aml=1 ]; then

   sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo bash -

   sudo yum -y install nodejs

else
   echo "Unsupported OS"
   exit -1
fi
```

The other reason of such error could be :- 
- not using correct shebang line in your mapper and reducer files AND 
 - passing mapper and reducer files which are saved in windows environment (in windows line endings) => use UNIX line endings to solve the problem.

Comment: I'd been trying to figure out how to get an EMR step to successfully run newer versions of nodejs (the official example script they provide is only for 0.12). Your code example finally got it to work. Frustrating that they don't have almost any support for nodejs in EMR